# How to understand the time spent in each step in execution plan?

Tags: sql-server

I am using `SQL Server` `Execution plan` to analysis my sql statement execution time. But I can't figure out the time spent on each step in the plan result. It looks like the result doesn't make sense to me.

In my query, I have turned on below options:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON
```

and I run the execution plan with `Actual Execution Plan` included. Below is the screenshot result:

[image]

There are some steps listed on the plan diagram and I can see each step execution time by clicking them and read the `Actual Time Statistics` on the right properties panel like below:

[image]

And in the message output I can see the total time for my query:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 331 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

You can see that it takes 331ms in total but the time spent on each step is very little which the most one is 14ms and most of others are 0. The total elapsed time from execution plan result is far less than the total 331ms. How can I understand the elapse time? Without that I can't figure out what the bottleneck in  my sql statement

Comment: Index seek are IO intensive, join, compute, aggregate and sort are CPU intensive, not consuming CPU much. There must be a high volume of data in your tables. Usually time elapsed equal CPU + IO time. IO can be disk/network access for read/write. What kind of disk do you have? Normal HDD, SSD or SAN?

Comment: I have SDD. I am trying to find out how much time each step consumes. Can I read this information from explain?

Comment: Is the objective to improve performance of the query? If so, just use the percentage amounts in the actual plan to try and isolate performance issues. Also use actual vs estimated rows

Comment: It is not only for performance improvement. More importantly, I'd like to know the time spent on each step in the execution plan. The percentage doesn't tell me the time.

Comment: @ZhaoYi because it doesn't matter. Queries are IO intensive. What matters is the *percentage* and the actual IO statistics, eg Estimated vs Actual Rows, logical reads, memory grants etc. The actual number of milliseconds doesn't really matter, especially in parallelized queries. You *won't* find bottlenecks by looking at CPU times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Execution Time` : Total time taken by Sql server to complete the execution of  compile plan.

`CPU Time` : Actual time spent on CPU.If `CPU time` is 0 that means Query is directly fetch from `cache plan`.
             If query is `compiling` and `recompiling` then CPU usage and `CPU time` will be more.
             There are other factor also which affect CPU time.

`Elapse Time` :Total time taken for the completion of the parse and compile including time taken to bring result to client.

Both are important to understand.If I want that showing result to client in quick time is very important then I may ignore `CPU time`.
So in this case `Elapse time` is important than `CPU Time`.

In other case I can ignore little higher `Elapse time` and concentrate in reducing high `CPU time`.

> Without that I can't figure out what the bottleneck in my sql
>   statement

`Execution Time(CPU+Elapse)` is itself not a bottleneck.It is just an indicator.
It it is not desirable then you have to investigate which `operator` is bottleneck
and take suitable action.

Like writing `optimize query` or `Index Tune` or change table schema or some other thing.

As per your query plan, `Hash Match` is considered to be most expensive operator.
Your main query is not visible.

You can also look that [Wait time](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/)

> why the total time spent in each plan is far less than the Elapsed
>   time reported from the message output window which is 331ms?

Suppose You have very simple query like,

```
Select * from Person.Person
```

In this case ,Each operator start executing after their right hand side operator has stop executing. In such scenario theoretically speaking,

```
Total Elapse Time is sum of each operator Elapse Time.
```

If query is directly executed from query plan or Elapse time is too small then it is rounded to 0.But theoretically,`Total Elapse Time is sum of each operator Elapse Time`.

Now take any complex query like your example,one or more operator start executing simultaneously and later merge into one,final Elapse time may be different.

Your main query plan is not completely visible else I would have tried to explain what I mean.

If you are using `Sql server 2016` or above then you can view how data is flowing and how multiple operator are working together.

[Live Query Statistics](https://littlekendra.com/2016/12/20/actual-time-statistics-in-execution-plans-elapsed-cpu-time-and-more/)

[Live Query Statistics](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3685/live-query-statistics-in-sql-server-2016/)

Even if you don't have Sql server 2016, you can still understand the actual matter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wonder how I can get the elapse time for each step in the execution plan?

Comment: @ZhaoYi , Right click on each Operator in Execution Plan --> Properties--> "Actual Statistics Time".

Comment: you mean "Actual Time Statistics" right? I already checked that. The question is why the total time spent in each plan is far less than the `Elapsed time` reported from the message output window which is 331ms?

Comment: @ZhaoYi , sorry I didn't answer the main question.You can read my edited.